# How to fix undershoots in data converted from Microstation using ArcMap 10.0?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, cad, microstation

I have converted data from Microstation to ArcGIS. The converted data has undershoots at intersections, so I tried to snap lines using Spatial Adjusment. I've added some control points but ArcMap didn't fix them.

**How can I fix the undershoots automatically?** I have many lines in my data, and fixing them manually would be too time consuming.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you are wanting to fix undershoots (and probably overshoots too) which is a different topic to spatial adjustment. Try using those terms to find suitable instructions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ET Geowizards has a tool if you do not have the licenses above but topology is the way to go if you do.

A possible workaround if they are all about the same length would be to create a feature class with a tolerance above the specified margin and load the data into the feature class.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to an ArcEditor (Standard) or ArcInfo (Advanced) license of ArcGIS Desktop there is a **[tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m600000037000000)** available on **Using geodatabase topology to fix line errors** such as undershoots and overshoots.

Unfortunately, the options for ArcView (Basic) are more manual and will involve **[extending lines](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//01m60000004w000000)** and or **[trimming lines](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Trimming_a_line_to_an_intersection_with_another_line/01m600000031000000/)**.